# Bring h3 outside p using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Input is -

```
    <data>
      <container>
        <strong>Code Development</strong>
        <br/>
        here to support
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>list 1</li>
          <li>list 2</li>
          <li>list 3</li>
          <li>list 4</li>
        </ul>
something here
<strong>this is strong</strong>
      </container>
    </data>
```

Expected Output -

```
            <h3>Code Development</h3>
        <p>
        here to support
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>list 1</li>
          <li>list 2</li>
          <li>list 3</li>
          <li>list 4</li>
        </ul>
      </p>

<h3>this is strong</h3>
<p>    something here</p>
```

strong tag should become h3 and since h3 can not be inside `<p>` so move it outside p as first one to appear before p .

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Michael - I want to handle h3 outside p tag and everything else inside p. Not sure, how to avoid just h3

Comment: I am afraid you are missing my point. If you have a specific difficulty, point it out - preferably, post what you have tried . Otherwise it looks like you're trying to get someone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="strong">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="."/></h3>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="container/text()">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space()) > 0">
            <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here is a practical example: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=5c53ab7f-0a1e-4fba-a608-4bb2d6ec1de0-xsltransformation#.VqDQ1SArK90

Comment: Thanks for this Ahmad. Actually, I need to place everything except strong tag , inside p tag. so, ul should come inside p. Just I need to avoid strong as h3 inside p and place it outside whenever a p tag is going to build.